# Team Foundation Server 2015 - Allow anonymous access to Web Portal

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to allow anonymous access to the tfs web portal?

Would be nice to be able to allow users who are not logged inn to access /tfs/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_dashboards and also preferably the information in the Work tab.

Tried adding the Everyone group in the Access levels tab. In the security tab for the collection and on the security tab for the project and also on the collection on the TFS server aswell as enabling Anonymous authentication on the IIS server but not having any luck.

Still getting a prompt to log on when trying to navigate to the dashboard and if I cancel that I get this error:

```
Error
The page you are looking for is currently unavailable.

TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

More information about this error
TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.
```

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TFS does not support anonymous access for now. Refer to the Q&A in this blog for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2015/02/23/vs-2015-ctp6-and-tfs-2015-ctp1-shipped-today/

> bharry
>
> @Karl, we don't currently have anonymous access in TFS 2015 but it's
>   been a hot topic lately.  We're looking at how we could get it done
>   before too long.

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked but do not think it is possible to day.
While you can go to IIS and enable Anonymous, TFS is designed in a way that each call to the server is tied to user previously authenticated.

I will not be surprised of a change in the future, because it is a limit for the service offered in VSTS; in fact you can only have private projects in today's VSTS. If this limitation is lifted in VSTS, we will get it for free in TFS.